# Non existence of continuous linear extension of the identity from continuous to bounded functions on [0,1]

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis

Is it true that there doesn't exist a linear continuous map from the space of bounded real functions on [0,1] to the space of continuous real functions on [0,1] whose restriction to the continuous functions is the identity?

Any comment or answer will be very highly apreciated. Thank you!